# AttributeError: module ' ' has no attribute ' '

Tags: python

I have 2 python files where I want to import from each to the other, however I get this error `AttributeError: module 'b' has no attribute 'y'`. I have already imported file `a` in file `b` and everything works. I want to access variable `y` from file `b` in file `a` but when I import file `b` in file `a`, I get this `AttributeError` which I know is from the circular imports. Is there any way I can access `y` variable from file `b` in file `a` after already importing file `a` in file `b`. Any suggestions are welcomed. Thanks in Advance. Below is a sample code for demonstration.

#### file b.py

```
import a
y = x + 2
```

#### file a.py

```
import b
for i in range(5):
     if b.y == 1:
        do_something()
     else:
        return
```

Comment: How are you running the code?

Comment: I suspect something like this: you run `python a.py`, which creates a module named `__main__` from the contents of `a.py`. To do this, you first have to import `b`, and *that* first has to import `a` ("again"). When defining the module `a` (rather than the module `__main__`, `b.y` does not yet exist), though the module `b` *itself* does.

Comment: As far as possible move active code (which does not only import or define something) into functions or classes. If possible even move imports into functions to avoid such situations. If "a.py" is the main file guard the active code with a `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Comment: @chepner, your suggestion is not really clear

Comment: I'm not really making a suggestion, other than "stop using circular imports". I'm just explaining why `b` has no attribute `y` when `a.py` tries to use it.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, I do not have a function in file ```a```, however I can put ```y``` within file ```b```  in a function and return ```y``` value in that function. In that case, how can I that function in the file ```a``` without encountering circular imports.

Comment: @chepner, Ok sure, that's why I asked in my post if there is a way to access the ```y``` variable in file ```a``` without importing file```b``` in file ```a```.

Comment: You have circular import between the two files, so import will fail. You can either put everything in one file, or extract the parts that they both need to use into a third file and import that from a and b instead

Comment: No. You can only import modules, not bits and pieces *of* modules.

Comment: A Python `import` is not a C `#INCLUDE`. It's an executable statement. One consequence is that mutually-referential code needs to be all in a single module. However much having the code in separate modules appeals to your sense of order (as, for example, one class per module), it's a technique that doesn't work well in a dynamic language.

Comment: @Anentropic, I have tried to extract the variables they both need into a third file by importing both a and b in the third file. However, I still get similar error when I import the third file in ```a``` and ```b```

Answer (score -2):

if you are using VSC make sure you save(ctrl s) every module you worked on, say; views.py.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).